# How to open Windows Explorer from SL app?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to a button in SL app to open Windows Explorer to point to a specific folder, for example, maybe a network driver \myserver\myfolder

How to implement this in code?

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenFileDialog to open up the explorer to load in a file. The initialdirectory property can be used to set the initial folder. Be careful with permissions though, you might need to make your silverlight app a trusted or out of browser app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog(v=vs.95).aspx